# How to optimize employee transport service?

Tags: algorithm, routes, maps, logic, transport

Gurus,

I am in the process of writing some code to optimize employee transport for corporate. I need all you expert's advice on how can this be achieved. Here is my scenario.

There are 100 pick up points all over city from where employees need to be brought to company with multiple vehicles. Each vehicle can occupy say 4 or 6 employees. My objective is to write some code which will group the people from nearby areas and bring them to company. Master data will have addresses and its latitude/longitude. I want to build an algorithm to optimize vehicle occupancy as well as distance and time. Could you guys please give some directions how can this be achieved. I understand I may need to use google maps or direction API for this but looking for some logic hint/advice how this can be achieved.

Some more inputs: These vehicles are of company's vehicle with driver. Travel time should not be more than 1.5 Hrs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having worked as a consultant in this industry this is an *extremely* broad question. Unfortunately questions this broad are not on topic here but have a look at my profile and get in contact, I'd happily give a few suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is a more complicated version of "The travelling salesman problem". You can look it up on and find some different examples and how they are implemented.

One point that need to be clarified : the vehicules to be use will be the employee vehicule that will be carshared or it will be company's vehicule with a driver?

You also need to define some time constrain. For example 50 employees should have under 30 min travel, 40 employe under 1h travel and 10 employe under 1,5H.

You also need to define the travel time for each road depending of the time, because at different time there will be traffic jam or not.

You also need to define group within the employee: usually people (admin clerck or CEO) in a company don't commute at the same time, it can have 1 hour range or more.

In fine, don't forget to include about 10% of the employee that wil be 2 to 5 min late to their meeting point.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your valulable inputs. The car will be company's vehicle with a driver. The travel time should not be more than 1.5Hrs. Will add these points in original question.

Comment: I also suggest you to start with the following, and after to extend to full problem : 10 people to pick up with 3 cars.
Once you solve this issue and write the code, the full problem should come more easy.